# Laravel eloquent relationship 4 table problem

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship

my db table is

```
===batches ===
id
batch_title

===courses===
id
course_title
batch_id

===students ===
id
name

===course_student===
course_id
student_id
```

now i want to show how many students are join in this batch and also how many students in this course

my **Student model**

```
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course');
}
```

**Course Model**

```
public function students(){

            return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Course','App\Student');
        }

    public function batch() {

                return $this->belongsTo('App\Batch','batch_id');
      }
```

**Batch Model**

```
public function courses(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Course','batch_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many weakness in your code:

first to should rebuild your many to many relation between Course and Student according to [many to many doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Student Model

```
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
}
```

Course Model

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
}
```

now: to get how many Student in this course:

```
$value = Course->withCount('students')->find($courseId);

$studentsCount = $value->students_count;
```

`$students_count` will have the student count for Course with `id = $couserId`

if you want to get Student Count for specific Batch will may walk in the same way:

```
$coursesInBatch = Course->withCount('students')->where('batch_id',$batchId)->get();
```

now `$coursesInBatch` holds the courses for this batch including there `students_count`

```
$studentCountInBatch = 0;

foreach ($coursesInBatch as $course) {
    $studentCountInBatch += $course->students_count;
}
```

now `$studentCountInBatch` will hold how many student in Batch with `id($batchId)`